# is there way to make Server Core is the default startup?

Tags: windows-server-2008, installation

I want to know if i can install windows server 2008 "full installation" and put the **Server Core** default startup and make the **server manager** is just Secondary option.
is that possible? , and how can do it?
thanks for every one

Comment: I don't think you can. Windows Server 2008 server core is essentially a different product from the normal install.

Comment: I also doubt it can be done, the whole point in server core is minimising the attack surface and hardware requirements by cutting out server manager and lots of other gui stuff.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. What does "Server Manager" have to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Windows Server 2008 and 2008 R2, you can not switch between Core and full server editions.  The purpose of core is to limit the files installed and services running. A reinstall is required to change them.

You can however, install Server Core edition and use Server Manager from another server to do most management tasks.